# django: set default locale for language?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm building a multilanguage site using modeltranslate, I can switch between languages no problem.

The problem comes with 'en' always being interpreted as 'en-us' which messes up the date formats everywhere.
It's a European site, I want 'en' to be interpreted as international English, or en-gb at least.

I've looked all over but can't see a way to do this. Is there any way to set a default locale for a language in Django? Do I need to set language to en-GB and have en-gb in the url? I really don't want to have to do a lot of coding on every template just to override the US date formatting ....

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-GB'

LANGUAGES = (
    ('es', _('Spanish')),
    ('ca', _('Catalan')),
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('fr', _('French')),
)
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT: I should probably add, it's not a browser issue, my browser language/locale is en-GB

Comment: Language have nothing to do with time. Its timezone settings you need to work on.

Comment: The question is not about timezones, it's to do with the datetimes getting formatted to month/day/year because django interprets en as en-us

Comment: Oh formatting. Thats tricky with multiple languages

Comment: {{ News_Item.pub_date|date:"DATE_FORMAT" }} does the job for every language, except that the English month/day is reversed. Numeric date format is unusable like this, 11/02/2020 in US is 02/11/2020 in pretty much every other country.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I have fixed this using a custom format file. ([See here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/formatting/#creating-custom-format-files))

For example, to 'alias' the language code `en` to `en-GB`, I added a format file at the path `appname.formats.en.formats` with the contents:

```py
from django.conf.locale.en_GB.formats import *
```

This imports all the GB locale (date/time) formatting for the language code `en`.

To make this work, the setting `FORMAT_MODULE_PATH` needs to be set to `appname.formats`.